# how to access an Excel Chart object using ExcelDNA

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I have a simple spreadsheet with a Chart on it, called ChartTESTER.xlsb.

I've created this C# function and called it from excel via ExcelDNA:

```
    public static string Chart_Test([ExcelArgument(AllowReference = true)]object relToCell)
    {
        var xlApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
        var cref = relToCell as ExcelReference;
        var cname = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlSheetNm, cref) as string;
        var workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks.Cast<Workbook>();
        string s1 = "";
        foreach (var aWb in workbooks)
        {
            s1 += "\n" + aWb.Name;
            s1 += ": " + aWb.Charts.Count;
        }
        return s1;
    }
```

and it returns:

> chartTESTER.xlsb: 0

So it's not finding the chart object in the workbook.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A Chart in the way you're using it is a type of worksheet.  If your chart is embedded then it's in a `ChartObject` on a worksheet - not sure if you can count those at the workbook level - you will likely need to iterate over the worksheets and check for `ChartObjects.Count`

Comment: great, thanks. That makes sense, and works